# How to make a div take all the remaining height AND display its scroll bar without making the browser have one too

Tags: css, html, scroll

I'm trying to combine different questions into a single answer yet none seem to do exactly what I'd like.

Given a div "container" with a div "spacer" of fixed height, another div "data" would take up a maximum of the remaining height of its parent, not break its parent's V-scroll, nor the browser's but instead have its own V-scroll only. Sounds simple enough.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="spacer">spacer</div>
    <div id="data">
        text<br/>
        text<br/>
        text<br/>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container { height:100% }
#spacer { height: 50px; }
#data
{ 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle example (gone wrong)](http://jsfiddle.net/mpprog/NqpGB/)

I keep breaking the V-scroll on the page (probably because the parent gets as high as the page, yet is shifted down by the fixed height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution which utilizes some absolute/relative positioning, if you don't mind using it.

The HTML structure remains the same (based on your JSFiddle). However, I did change/add to your CSS definitions, so they ended up looking like this (the `margin:0` is just so the body isn't rendered with unwanted spacing around it):

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    height:100%
    position: relative;
}
#spacer {
    height: 50px;
}
#data {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

This will allow `#data` to expand vertically to fill all the space that `#spacer` does not already take in `#container`. However, it will only go as far as a bottom of `#container`, which in this case is the bottom of the viewport (due to `height:100%`). Any additional content will scroll inside the `#data` element. Note that this only works if you know the exact or relative height of the `#spacer` element, which you seem to know here.

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqpGB/4/) showing what this achieves. If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

height:100% doesn't work here. Add this line to your onload routine (the 55 accounts for your header):

```
document.getElementById("container").style.height=document.body.clientHeight-55 +"px"
```

Also, set css body {overflow:hidden}